# Calculo IMC retnornando NaN JS

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo problema no cálculo simples de IMC já tentei de tudo mas não consigo resolver.

O retorno do cálculo é sempre NaN.

Código:

```
let paciente_um = document.querySelector("#primeiroPaciente");

let tdpeso = paciente_um.querySelector(".info-peso");

tdpeso.textContent ="200";

let tdAltura = paciente_um.querySelector(".info-altura");
tdAltura.textContent = "4.00";

let imc = tdpeso/(tdAltura*tdAltura);
let tdImc = paciente_um.querySelector(".info-imc");
tdimc.textContent = imc;
```

```
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="titulo">Aparecida Nutrição</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section class="container">
                <h2>Meus pacientes</h2>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Peso(kg)</th>
                            <th>Altura(m)</th>
                            <th>Gordura Corporal(%)</th>
                            <th>IMC</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tabela-pacientes">
                        <tr class="paciente" id="primeiroPaciente" >
                            <td class="info-nome">Paulo</td>
                            <td class="info-peso">100</td>
                            <td class="info-altura">2.00</td>
                            <td class="info-gordura">10</td>
                            <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="paciente" >
                            <td class="info-nome">João</td>
                            <td class="info-peso">80</td>
                            <td class="info-altura">1.72</td>
                            <td class="info-gordura">40</td>
                            <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="paciente" >
                            <td class="info-nome">Erica</td>
                            <td class="info-peso">54</td>
                            <td class="info-altura">1.64</td>
                            <td class="info-gordura">14</td>
                            <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="paciente">
                            <td class="info-nome">Douglas</td>
                            <td class="info-peso">85</td>
                            <td class="info-altura">1.73</td>
                            <td class="info-gordura">24</td>
                            <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="paciente" >
                            <td class="info-nome">Tatiana</td>
                            <td class="info-peso">46</td>
                            <td class="info-altura">1.55</td>
                            <td class="info-gordura">19</td>
                            <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </section>
        </main>

        <script src="js/principal.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Comment: Está tentando efetuar operações matemáticas com o tipo "string".

Answer (score 0):

Sim lucas resolveu o problema, porem apenas criei uma variavel para receber a propriedade peso.textContent e altura.

```
let paciente_um = document.querySelector("#primeiroPaciente"); 

let tdpeso = paciente_um.querySelector(".info-peso");

let peso = tdpeso.textContent = 100; 

let tdAltura = paciente_um.querySelector(".info-altura");
let altura = tdAltura.textContent = 1.70;

let imc = peso/(altura*altura); 

let tdImc = paciente_um.querySelector(".info-imc");
tdImc.textContent = imc;
```

Comment: `peso = tdpeso.textContent = 100`  - aqui vc está mudando o `textContent` para 100 e depois setando esse mesmo valor no `peso`. Mas se quer apenas pegar o valor que já está no elemento (e não mudá-lo), faça apenas `peso = tdpeso.textContent`. Já usar `innerHTML` como sugeriu a outra resposta não é recomendado para o que vc quer fazer (que é pegar o **texto** - e não o HTML - do elemento). Tudo bem que nesse caso "funciona" por coincidência, já que não tem outras tags HTML dentro do `td`, mas fica o alerta (e para se aprofundar no assunto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428100)

Comment: obrigado @hkotsubo entendi seu comentário e vou ler este conteúdo, eu atribuir o valor 100 somente para ver no navegador se realmente estava funcionando.

Answer (score -2):

Como @Danizavtz disse, você não pode realizar cálculos com o tipo `string` (que são os dados exibidos na tabela).
Você também não está acessando os valores das células da tabela.
Tenta esse código:

```js
let paciente_um = document.querySelector("#primeiroPaciente");

let tdpeso = parseFloat(paciente_um.querySelector(".info-peso").innerHTML);

let tdAltura = parseFloat(paciente_um.querySelector(".info-altura").innerHTML);

let imc = tdpeso/(tdAltura*tdAltura);
let tdImc = paciente_um.querySelector(".info-imc");
tdImc.textContent = imc;
```

Comment: to vendo as pessoas classificando a pergunta com negativo, porem pessoal como é obvio estou apreendendo e ao invés de querer de pagar de sabidão e se  pergunta não está no seu nivel, bem se mostra o nivel de pessoa que você é.                                                                Obrigado aos colegas  pelo tempo em ajudar

Comment: Cara, fiz um comentário em [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/553481/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-retornando-somente-undefined#comment985778_553486](outra pergunta) sobre essa questão da negativação. Isso é como uma forma de "punir" os usuários caso alguém ache algo de errado com a pergunta/resposta como se os pontos fossem o foco principal. Isso me faz pensar que algumas pessoas estão aqui para acumular pontos só invés de tentar simplesmente ajudar.

Comment: Mas diz aí, deu certo esse código?

Comment: Tá bem difícil ajudar com tantas regras na versão pt-br oposto de versão e. Se fosse para desconsiderar avalie a escrita os erros de português de concordância de tempo a falta da contextualização mas leva negativo o iniciante e quem sede um tempo para auxiliar 